# How to send XML in request body of a GET API using JavaScript in Cypress. Sending request in JSON format gives response as Input was not well formed

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I am hitting an API and this API returns XML response. JavaScript code in Cypress is as follow -

```
        describe('Loan Details', ()=>{
     
       it('Get loan details', ()=>{
         cy.request({
         method : 'GET',
         url    : '/services/getLoans/getLoans.aspx',
         headers : {
             'api_user_id' : 'abc',
             'api_password': 'def',
             'loan_id'     : '8411'
         }
     }).then((res)=>{
        expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
        let myxml = Cypress.$.parseXML(res.body)
       cy.log(res.body)
       }) 
     }) 
    })
```

When I execute this code I am getting following output -

```
 assert  expected 200 to equal 200
 log   <OUTPUT version="2.1"><ERROR type="NOT_WELL_FORMED">Input was not well formed and xml compliant.</ERROR></OUTPUT>
```

Therefore I am getting desired response that is 200 (success) from API but in order to validate loan data like loan_type, loan_number for a particular loan_id etc.
I am pasting sample API response which we are getting after hitting the GET API.

```
   <OUTPUT version="2.0">
    <RESPONSE>
    <LOAN_DATA 
        loan_id="8411" 
        loan_number="61036" 
        loan_type="VL" 
        status_code="OK">
        <![CDATA[<VEHICLE_LOAN xmlns="abc.com" version="5.259"><APPLICANTS><APPLICANT paper_grade="" is_declined="N" first_name="CO APPLICANT F" last_name="TESTCASE" m_initial="" middle_name="" ssn="000000001" dob="1990-01-01" ages_of_dependents="" mother_maiden_name="" citizenship="USCITIZEN" member_number="" bankruptcy_score="0" membership_months="0" marital_status="MARRIED" number_in_household="1" credit_score="745" custom_score="0" custom_score_2="670" custom_score_3="690" custom_score_4="670" custom_score_5="670" applicant_type="P" allow_direct_mail="Y" allow_email_solicit="Y" allow_telemarket="Y" allow_share_info="Y" is_ofac_id_ver="N" id_authentication_result="INCOMPLETE" is_fraud_prescore="N" contact_index="0" d3p1:internal_borrower_id="5911" is_fraud_credit="N" is_ofac_credit="N" combined_unsecured_aggregate_amount_with_lender="0.00" combined_secured_aggregate_amount_with_lender_no_mortgage="0.00" borrower_id="0" xmlns:d3p1="abc.com"><ID_CARD card_type="SOCIAL_SECURITY" card_number="00-000-0006" state="" country="USA" /><ID_CARD2 card_type="" card_number="" state="" country="" /><CURRENT_ADDRESS occupancy_status="GOVQUARTERS" occupancy_duration="12" other_occupancy_description=""><LOOSE_ADDRESS street_address_1="123, CO APPLCIANT ADDRESS" street_address_2="" city="JACKSONVILLE" state="FL" zip="32259" county="" address_verification_date="2020-06-02" /></CURRENT_ADDRESS><PREVIOUS_ADDRESS occupancy_status="GOVQUARTERS" occupancy_duration="13" other_occupancy_description="" city="JACKSONVILLE" state="FL" zip="32259" county="" street_address_1="123, joint applciant address" street_address_2="" country="USA" /><MAILING_ADDRESS city="JACKSONVILLE" state="FL" zip="32259" county="" street_address_1="123, CO APPLCIANT ADDRESS" street_address_2="" country="USA" address_verification_date="2020-06-02" is_current="Y" /><FINANCIAL_INFO><CURRENT_EMPLOYMENT employment_start_date="2020-01-01" employed_months="26" employment_address="employment Address" employment_city="" employment_state="" occupation="Test Professional Job" employer="MERDIANLINK" employment_phone="" employment_status="EM" employment_weekly_hours="0" is_employee_of_lender="Y" employee_of_lender_type="EMPLOYEE" profession_months="26" /><PREVIOUS_EMPLOYMENT monthly_income="1000.00" employed_months="0" employment_address="EMP Addrtess" employment_city="" employment_state="" occupation="" employer="" employment_phone="" employment_weekly_hours="0" /><MONTHLY_INCOME is_monthly_income_base_salary_manual="N" is_bah_included="N" monthly_income_base_salary="5000.00" is_tax_exempt_monthly_income_base_salary="Y" monthly_income_over_time="0.00" monthly_income_bonus="0.00" income_verify_method="" /><MONTHLY_DEBT monthly_liability="1389.00" monthly_housing_cost="100.00" monthly_rent="100.00" job_expense="100.00" alimony="0.00" child_support="150.00" separate_maintenance_expense="0.00" tax_expense="0.00" other_expense_1="0.00" other_expense_2="0.00" monthly_mortgage_payment="0.00" aggregate_amount_with_lender="0.00" aggregate_amount_with_lender_secured_no_mortgage="0.00" /></FINANCIAL_INFO><REFERENCE first_name="" last_name="" address="" city="" state="" phone="" relationship="" email="" /><REFERENCE first_name="" last_name="" address="" city="" state="" phone="" relationship="" email="" /><CONTACT_INFO preferred_contact_method="HOME" cell_phone="" cell_phone_country="US" fax_number="" fax_number_country="US" home_phone="(999) 888-7776" home_phone_country="US" work_phone="" work_phone_extension="" work_phone_country="US" email="COAPPL@def.COM" /><ASSETS /><DECLARATIONS has_judge_bankrupt_foreclosure="" has_declare_bankrupt="" has_chapter_13="" has_lawsuit_party="" has_judgement="" has_foreclosure="" has_reposession="" has_other_obligation="" has_past_due_bills="" has_co_maker="" co_maker_amount="0.00" has_alias="" has_income_decline="" has_suits_pending="" has_alimony="" has_property_for_sale="" /></APPLICANT></APPLICANTS><LOAN_INFO rate_code="" payment_due_day="0" max_underwrite_amount="0" epl_fees_total="0.00" is_claimed="Y" is_complete_consumer="N" require_product_refresh="N" is_addon="N" is_amendment="N" solve_for="PAYMENT" override_code="04" is_possible_dupe="N" app_subtype="DVL" is_workout_loan="N" is_solvefor_manual="N" tier="0" tier_previous="0" is_prequalification_applied="N" is_ofac="N" is_indirect_loan="N" is_business="N" total_sales_price="0.00" total_vehicle_value="2000.00" amount_requested="1000.00" down_payment="0.00" loan_term="36" contract_rate="0.00000" trade_allowance="0.00" initial_balloon_amount="0.00" estimated_vehicle_payment="0.00" is_residual_loan="N" rebate="0.00" tax="0.00" license="0.00" additional_items_front_end="0.00" additional_items_back_end="0.00" max_advance="" max_advance_value="0.00" max_soft_advance_value="0.00" max_hard_advance_value="0.00" amount_approved="0.00" request_type="AUTO SECURED" purpose_type="AUTO SECURED" inspected_by="" misc_implant="" number_of_payments="0" is_balloon="N" is_hmda="N" is_hmda_manual="N" amount_approved_variance="0.00" is_advance_request="N" is_calculate_mapr="Y" mapr="0.00000" customer_money_factor="0" lender_money_factor="0" residual_value="0.00" gross_cap_cost="0.00" cap_cost_reduction="0.00" adjusted_cap_cost="0.00" lease_payment="0.00" max_lease_payment="0.00" security_deposit="0.00" net_due_to_dealer="0.00" /><PRICE_ADJUSTMENTS /><LOAN_STATUS loan_status="APP" approval_date="2022-03-02T02:00:57-08:00" first_approval_date="2022-03-02T01:59:34-08:00" response_date="2022-03-02T01:59:34-08:00" initial_entry_timestamp="2022-03-02T01:46:32-08:00" last_modified="2022-03-02T02:04:03-08:00" is_locked="N" existing_balance="0.00" delinquency_period="0" delinquency_amount="0.00" deciding_date="2022-03-02" app_receive_date="2022-03-02T01:46:32-08:00" amount_charge_off="0.00" /><DISBURSEMENTS /><TASK_LIST /><FUNDING daily_periodic_rate="0.00000" payment_frequency="MONTHLY" funded_status="FUN" funding_date="2022-03-02" amount_advanced="900.00" current_payment="0.00" filing_fee_amount="0.00" filing_fee_type="FINANCED" finance_charge="0.00" initial_amount_advanced="900.00" other_charges="0.00" other_charges_description="" other_loans="0.00" prev_loan_liner_balance="0.00" total_financed_payment="900.00" interest_only_min_payment="0.00" interest_only_max_payment="0.00" loan_term="0" reserve_amount="0.00" primary_reserve_amount="0.00" secondary_reserve_amount="0.00" suggested_buydown_amount="0.00" extended_rate="0.00000" buy_rate="0.00000" contract_rate="0.00000" index="0.00000" margin="0.00000" floor="0.00000" ceiling="0.00000" apr="0.00000" exact_monthly_payment="120.00" exact_monthly_payment_original="0.00" exact_last_monthly_payment="0.00" additional_fees="0.00" additional_fees_comment="" funding_acquisition_fee="0.00" initial_rate="-999999.00000" doc_stamps_fee="0.00" doc_stamps_rate="0.00000" doc_stamps_fee_is_manual="N" doc_stamps_type="FINANCED" funding_money_factor="0" funding_equivalent_interest_rate="0.00000" funding_allowable_annual_mileage="0"><SKIP_PAYMENT_INFO skip_start_date="0001-01-01" skip_end_date="0001-01-01" skip_period_month_day_start="0001-01-01" skip_period_month_day_end="0001-01-01" skips_per_year="0" position_of_skips="0" is_position_of_skips_first_pay_skip="N" is_defer_skip_payments="N" /><INSURANCE_OPTIONS loan_class="C" description="" is_mapr_gap="Y" is_mapr_sc="N" is_mapr_vpp="N"><INSURANCE_OPTION type="GAP" premium="0.00" is_financed="Y" /><INSURANCE_OPTION type="SERVICE_CONTRACT" premium="0.00" is_financed="Y" /><INSURANCE_OPTION type="VPP" premium="0.00" is_financed="Y" /></INSURANCE_OPTIONS><CLOSE_END_INFO amount_owed_to_lender="900.00" amount_refinanced="0.00" cash_prepaid_finance_charge="0.00" mapr_cash_fee="0.00" /></FUNDING><COMMENTS><DECISION_COMMENTS>Kumar, Amit (3/2/2022 5:00:57 AM EST): DONT GO THERE
        </DECISION_COMMENTS><EXTERNAL_COMMENTS></EXTERNAL_COMMENTS><INTERNAL_COMMENTS></INTERNAL_COMMENTS><UNABLE_TO_FUND></UNABLE_TO_FUND></COMMENTS><STRUCTURED_COMMENTS><STRUCTURED_INTERNAL_COMMENTS><STRUCTURED_COMMENT modifier_type="Z" last_modified_date="2022-03-02T01:48:54.0000000-08:00" creation_date="2022-03-02T01:48:54.0000000-08:00" message="Applicant (TESTCASE, CO APPLICANT F) has a record in the Applicant Designation.  The applicant's Employee Of Lender Type is set to: EMPLOYEE"><MODIFIER d5p1:internal_id="00000000000000000000000000000001" xmlns:d5p1="abc.com" /></STRUCTURED_COMMENT><STRUCTURED_COMMENT modifier_type="Z" last_modified_date="2022-03-02T01:59:56.0000000-08:00" creation_date="2022-03-02T01:59:56.0000000-08:00" message="Switched to pending status because amount approved has increase from 0 to 900"><MODIFIER d5p1:internal_id="00000000000000000000000000000001" xmlns:d5p1="abc.com" /></STRUCTURED_COMMENT></STRUCTURED_INTERNAL_COMMENTS></STRUCTURED_COMMENTS><VEHICLES><VEHICLE mileage="5" is_new_vehicle="Y" vehicle_sales_price="0.00" vehicle_value="2000.00" is_rebuilt_restored="N" processing_type="CT" vehicle_options="SUN ROOF - FLIP" vin="" vehicle_type="CAR" year="2022" make="BENTLEY" model="test" license="" nada_info="" body_type="" empty_weight="0" carrying_capacity="0" length="0" commercial_title="NONE"><CLEAR_TITLE current_name_on_title="TESTCASE, CO APPLICANT F" new_names_on_title="TESTCASE, CO APPLICANT F" name_for_collateral_purposes="TESTCASE, CO APPLICANT F" title_recording_fees="0.00" current_name_on_title_contact_index="0" new_names_on_title_contact_index="0" name_for_collateral_purposes_contact_index="0" /><TITLE state_current="" /><INSURANCE /></VEHICLE><TRADE_IN trade_value="0.00" trade_payoff="0.00" trade_payment="0.00" vin="" vehicle_type="CAR" year="0" make="" model="" /></VEHICLES><CUSTOM_QUESTIONS /><CONTACTS><CONTACT_INFO contact_type="APPLICANT" first_name="CO APPLICANT F" last_name="TESTCASE" address="123, CO APPLCIANT ADDRESS" city="JACKSONVILLE" state="FL" zip="32259" phone="(999) 888-7776" email="COAPPL@def.COM" ssn="000000001" is_ssn_taxid="N" dob="1990-01-01" /></CONTACTS><SYSTEM type="LPQ" d2p1:loan_id="892fb4" xmlns:d2p1="abc.com"><PROCESSOR d2p1:internal_id="4cc78ffcca0d" name="test" phone="(989) 898-9800" code="TEST_301" email="test@abc.com" /><LOAN_OFFICER d2p1:phone="(989) 898-9898" code="TEST_301" email="test@abc.com" /><APPROVAL_OFFICER d2p1:phone="(989) 898-9898" code="TEST_301" email="test@abc.com" /><FUNDER d2p1:phone="(989) 898-9898" code="TEST_301" email="test@abc.com" /><DECIDING_OFFICER d2p1:phone="(989) 898-9898" code="TEST_301" email="test@abc.com" /><ORIGINATOR d2p1:internal_id="4cc78ffcca0" name="test" phone="(989) 898-9898" code="TEST_301" email="test@abc.com" type="L" /><BRANCH d2p1:internal_id="0c845c56bf89e232e" name="Branch1" code="BRANCH1_217" phone="714-651-5553" fax="324-234-2342,123-456-7899, 123-456-6565" email="dvu@abc.com" reference_id2="2"><ADDRESS street_address_1="1600 Sunflower Ave" city="Costa Mesa" state="CA" zip="92626" /></BRANCH><LENDER d2p1:internal_id="cb8f7cda8a6" name="Lender Hive" reference_id="UnitTestReference" code="PleaseChangeMe_6688a99921444657ba0c318471f05ecd" phone="714-333-2988" fax="714-333-2988" email="ben@abc.com" cuna_client_id="10416516"><ADDRESS street_address_1="144327 Corky St." city="Westminster" state="IL" zip="29375" /></LENDER><ORGANIZATION d2p1:internal_id="7fcd0b9452ca46a7a194bc3f2324905e" name="QA-Hive" reference_id="UnitTestOrgReference" code="QA-Hive" phone="(714) 333-2988" fax="(714) 333-2988" /><CLOSING_BRANCH d2p1:internal_id="0c84532e" name="Branch1" reference_id="1" code="BRANCH1_217" phone="714-651-5553" fax="324-234-2342,123-456-7899, 123-456-6565" email="dvu@abc.com" reference_id2="2"><ADDRESS street_address_1="1600 Sunflower Ave" city="Costa Mesa" state="CA" zip="92626" /></CLOSING_BRANCH></SYSTEM><HMDA_INFO is_hoepa="N" is_hoepa_manual="N" lien_position="1" purchaser="NOT_ORIGINATED" /><HMDA_XML version="2018" xmlns="abc.com"></HMDA_XML><VEHICLE_BUSINESS_INFORMATIONS number_of_employees="0" months_in_business="0" is_borrower_prepared="N" is_cpa_prepared="N" is_income_tax_statements_available="N" mailing_address_is_current="Y" mailing_country="USA" occupancy_duration="0" /></VEHICLE_LOAN>]]>
     </LOAN_DATA>
   </RESPONSE>
  </OUTPUT>
```

Just got to know that input to this should only be in XML format. I am adding input XML as well here for better understanding.

```
      <INPUT>
           <LOGIN api_user_id="f782481b" api_password="Sn63P73P"/>
            <REQUEST>
               <LOAN loan_id="d023bcf"/>
            </REQUEST>
      </INPUT>
```

Please help me get this resolved. I was thinking to store the response in a variable/constant and then apply some methods but it did not work.

Comment: Can you put the entirety of the XML? As it currently is, the XML is well-formed, but there may be some data underneath `<VEHICLE_LOAN>` that is causing it to be malformed.

Comment: Why is it `<OUTPUT version="2.1">` in the error and `<OUTPUT version="2.0">` in the sample?

Comment: @TesterDick I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @agoff, I have added entire XML. Please have a look.

Comment: Hi @agoff, I have added complete details here in this thread. It may help understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried multiple ways to pass request XML format and finally able to get desired response. Please see below the working code -

```
   describe('Loan Details', () => {
     it('Info', () => {
     cy.readFile('D:/Cypress/CypressPractice/myRequest.xml')
      .then(text => fetchXML(text))
      .then(response =>{
          expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
          cy.log(response.body)
      })
          
   function fetchXML(text){
       return cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/services/getLoans/getLoans.aspx',
        body : text
       })
     }
   })
 })
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how this works, as the data for the GET request should be attached to the URL of the request, and the body of the request doesn't even exist ..?

Comment: @Teemu, body is being read from myRequest.xml file placed at my local drive using readFile method.
As per specification of our legacy API we are not passing any headers and only userid/password & request tag in xml format being passed as body. Believe me it works like a charm.